# What is the best way to create nested POJO classes for a dynamic JSON key in a Nested JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, struts2

I'm calling the rest service with a body as JSON. It is necessary to create a POJO class in Java, but I am unsure of how to do so for a dynamic JOSN key within a nested JSON object.

The keys are dynamic under parents, childs and fills. It would be great if someone suggests how to create nested POJO to do the same

**JSON**

```json
{
  "Id": "msft",
  "userId": "john",
  "timezone": "EST",
  "parents": {
    "symbol": {
      "displayName": "symbol",
      "dataType": "string",
      "aggregateType": "sum",
      "isFrozen": true,
      "isDisplayed": true,
      "isJsonColumn": false,
      "rank": 1
    },
    "date": {
      "displayName": "date",
      "dataType": "date",
      "aggregateType": "sum",
      "isFrozen": true,
      "isDisplayed": true,
      "isJsonColumn": false,
      "rank": 2
    }
  },
  "childs": {
    "qty": {
      "displayName": "qty",
      "dataType": "string",
      "aggregateType": "sum",
      "isFrozen": true,
      "isDisplayed": true,
      "isJsonColumn": false,
      "rank": 1
    },
    "price": {
      "displayName": "price",
      "dataType": "date",
      "aggregateType": "sum",
      "isFrozen": true,
      "isDisplayed": true,
      "isJsonColumn": false,
      "rank": 2
    }
  },
  "fills": {
    "account": {
      "displayName": "account",
      "dataType": "string",
      "aggregateType": "sum",
      "isFrozen": true,
      "isDisplayed": true,
      "isJsonColumn": false,
      "rank": 1
    },
    "name": {
      "displayName": "name",
      "dataType": "date",
      "aggregateType": "sum",
      "isFrozen": true,
      "isDisplayed": true,
      "isJsonColumn": false,
      "rank": 2
    }
  }
}
```

**POJO**

**UserConfig**

```
public class UserConfig {
    String Id;
    String userId;
    String timezone;
    Map<String,ColumnConfig> parents;
    Map<String,ColumnConfig> childs;
    Map<String,ColumnConfig> fills;
    // getters and setters
}
```

**ColumnConfig**

```
public class ColumnConfig {
    String displayName;
    String dataType;
    String aggregateTyep;
    boolean isFrozen;
    boolean isDisplayed;
    boolean isJsonColumn;
    int rank;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: What deserializer did you use?

Answer (score 0):

1. maybe you can create POJO with some JSONObject Field like this

```java
class XXXPojo{
    String id;
    String userId;
    ...
    JSONObject parents;
    JSONObject childs;
    JSONObject fills;

}
```

2. Use a POJO with all filed that can appear in `parents`,`childs`,`fills`
3. why dynamic key? maybe you can solve this problem if you solve dynamic key

Comment: Giving nulls for the dynamic keys as It is unable to parse the inner objects